# R: coerce 'externalptr' into character

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am debugging parallel code that uses Rhpc package.  Rhpc stores the
cluster data into an `externlaptr` objects.  I want to test if it
is not corrupt, and hence somehow output it's value into a file by
`write`.

The code looks like this:

```
library(Rhpc)
Rhpc_initialize()
cl <- Rhpc_getHandle(1)
print(cl)
```

`print` works, but is there a way to convert it into a
`character` object to be outputted with `write()`?
`as.character`, `as(cl, "character")`, `as(cl, "integer")`
etc give an error `cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of
type 'character'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `capture.output`:

```
make_nil()
# <pointer: (nil)>

capture.output(make_nil())
# [1] "<pointer: (nil)>"

capture.output(make_nil()) == "<pointer: (nil)>"
# [1] TRUE
```

You're technically not coercing the the `externalptr` itself to `character`, that's just used to represent its address; but if all you are using that for is to check if it is valid or not, you should be fine.

---

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<int> make_nil() {
    int* p = 0;
    return Rcpp::XPtr<int>(p);
}
```